# What will be the scala equivalent of the following python code?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

```
men = data.flatMap(lambda x :x['text'].split(" ")) \
.filter(lambda x: len(x.strip()) > 1) \
.filter(lambda x : x[0] == '@') \
.map(lambda x:x.replace('@',''))
```

I tried but I'm unable to solve it.

```
var men=df.map((df.select("text"))
          .split(" ")).filter(x => (x.strip()).length()>1)
          .filter(x=>x(0)=="@")
          .map(x=>x.replace("@",""))
```

> :35: error: value split is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

here df is my DataFrame, text is the name of the column that I'm working on.

Comment: Does the Python code work? Seems that you calling `replace` on a boolean...

Comment: It looks that Python data variable is a RDD...

Comment: You have to use `flatMap()` in the same way as in Python. for instance, `df.flatMap( df => df.select("test").split(" ") ...`.

Comment: yes the python data variable is a RDD @EmiCareOfCell44

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have `text` column in your `dataframe` and you are trying to `split` the *text in that column* and then `filter` words with *@* sign at the beginning and finally `replace` *@ sign with empty char*.

If my understanding is correct then following can be the equivalent code in scala

```
var men=df.rdd.flatMap(x => x.getAs[String]("text").split(" "))
    .filter(x => x.trim.length > 1)
    .filter(x => x.startsWith("@"))
    .map(x => x.replace("@", ""))
```